# Maven build: set settings.xml path from environment variable

Tags: java, maven, build

How can I set the path of the settings.xml from environment variable in a mvn build?

I have tried:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-s /tmp/settings.xml"
```

or

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="--settings /tmp/settings.xml"
```

but it not works.

I need it, because I cannot modify the build command.

Comment: You can modify environment variables, but not the build command? Why that?

Comment: It is a gitlab-ci build, I cannot modify the repo, but I can modify the environment variables in group level.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this in your gitlab-ci build script, just before calling `mvn`:
(see https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-maven-config-file)

```sh
mkdir -p .mvn && echo "-s /tmp/settings.xml" >> .mvn/maven.config
```

This does not modify the repo, only adds a file to the local checkout within the running build job.

---

**Starting with Maven 4** this should also work:

```sh
export MAVEN_ARGS="-s /tmp/settings.xml"
```

see https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#maven_args-environment-variable

Comment: technically it seems that MAVEN_ARGS works with Maven 3.9+ not just Maven 4 - which is helpful since it seems that Maven 4 isn't released yet